# How can I export data from a HTML form to csv file using php

Tags: php, html, forms, csv

I have a HTML form constructed by a couple of drop down select fields.
The submit button generates a string.

I need help exporting each string generated to a CSV file. My first thoughts are to take the string from the field and place it in a HTML table, then use a script for exporting it to a file.

I'd appreciate it if you can provide a working example.

I am very green in this, so please write slowly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is simply a comma seperated vector.

So each string can be written to a file so that they are separated by commas if you want them in separate columns, or by carriage returns if you want them on separate lines.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
my question though wasn't about how CSV files work. I need an example for a working code to write the strings i generate to a HTML table and then download it as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

The csv export didn't work, so i am trying to print the text input (that i am generating) to a text area, one by one and it works fine.

The problem now is that i want to place a "br" after each link i move to the text area. any ideas? here is my code:

```
<input name="result" size="70" class="result" type="text" ></input>
<input type="button" value="Add The Link" onClick="addtext();"></p>
<textarea style="width:509px;" name="outputtext"></textarea><br><br>
<input value="Clear" type="reset">
```

and in the head are is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addtext() {
    var newtext = document.cwm1.result.value;
    document.cwm1.outputtext.value += newtext;
}
</script>
```

Thanks